# C# async/await and showing dialog

Tags: c#, user-interface, asynchronous

How to deal, if a need to show dialog inside await function?

for example plz consider this c# pseudo-code:

```
async Task loginButton_Click(...args...)
{
    disable_some_gui_controls();

    var svc = new WebSite();

    // get captcha from user
    svc.OnCaptcha += () =>
    {
       var captcha = new CaptchaForm();
       captcha.ShowDialog(this);
       return captcha.UserCaptcha;
    }

    // login may ask captcha
    await svc.Login("user", "password");

    if (login.Success)
        enable_some_gui_controls();
}
```

run dialog from await code leads to cross-thread exception.

```
class WebSite
{
    public delegate string Captcha();
    public event Captcha OnCaptcha;

    public async Task<bool> Login(...args...)
    {
        ...
        if (needs captcha)
        {
           string captchaText = OnCaptcha();
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What method shows the dialog? `loginButton_Click` or `svc.Login`? Because you've said "`await` code".. yet the dialog is shown outside of the `await` usage.

Comment: if captcha is needed, the Login method sends event. It executes inside Login

Comment: You haven't answered my question. How is this method called? Is this method itself awaited?

Comment: this in how it work in Login method (post updated)

Comment: If that's your actual code, then it should work fine. There's nothing in the `WebSite` class that is placing `OnCaptcha` on a background thread. If that's not your actual code, then please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use invoke to call the form methods on the main thread:

```
var captcha = new CaptchaForm();
var result = captcha.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
    captcha.ShowDialog(this);
    return captcha.UserCaptcha;
}));
```